# Mysql 5.7 Issue in declare handler for duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

We are facing an issue in declaring handlers in MYSQL 5.7 stored procedure.
Using the documentation present in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html, I'm trying to create handler in my stored procedure to do the following:

1. If a duplicate key appears, log it and move on insert good row.
2. End of the stored proc, get me all the error and success rows inserted.

As you can see below, we don't have primary key for table, however have the unique key constraint.

**Input**

```
CALL userTableInsert('{"userid":100, "username":"Hello"}, {"userid":102, "username":"World"}, {"userid":102, "username":"World"}', @got_dups)
```

**Expected Output**

```
100:Hello should get inserted and 102:World should get errored out and status needs to be corrected depicted in the output of the stored procedure.
```

**Getting ERR** : Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ...'

```
Table: user_table
CREATE TABLE `user_table` (
  user_id int(20) NOT NULL,
  user_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  created_by varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  created_date date NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `user_ukey` (user_id, user_name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


 ===============================================
 Stored Procedure
 ===============================================



DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS schema.userTableInsert$$
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.userTableInsert(IN JSONArrayParam MEDIUMTEXT, OUT 
got_dups INT)
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

DECLARE code CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE msg TEXT;
DECLARE rows INT;
DECLARE result TEXT;

DECLARE rowsJSON MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
SET rowsJSON = TRIM(JSONArrayParam);
SET rowsJSON = TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM rowsJSON);
SET rowsJSON = TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM rowsJSON);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS rowsToUse;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rowsToUse (
     user_id INT NOT NULL,
     user_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY;


WHILE (rowsJSON != '') DO
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rowJSON VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE temp JSON;
        DECLARE userid INT DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE username VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;

        SET rowJSON = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rowsJSON, '}', 1), '}');

        SET temp = JSON_EXTRACT(rowJSON, '$.userid');
        SET userid = COALESCE(IF(JSON_TYPE(temp) = 'NULL', NULL, REPLACE(temp, '\"', '')));

        SET temp = JSON_EXTRACT(rowJSON, '$.username');
        SET username = COALESCE(IF(JSON_TYPE(temp) = 'NULL', NULL, REPLACE(temp, '\"', '')));

        INSERT INTO rowsToUse(user_id, user_name)
        VALUES(userid, username);

        IF LOCATE('{', rowsJSON, 2) > 0 THEN
            SET rowsJSON = SUBSTRING(rowsJSON, LOCATE('{', rowsJSON, 2));
        ELSE
            SET rowsJSON = '';
        END IF;        
    END;
END WHILE;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

 # Getting syntax error here
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062
  BEGIN
  GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
  END;

 INSERT INTO user_table(user_id, user_name, created_by , created_date)
 SELECT user_id, user_name, 'system', NOW()
 FROM rowsToUse;


IF code = '00000' THEN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;
    SET result = CONCAT('insert succeeded, row count = ',rows);
ELSE
    SET result = CONCAT('insert failed, error = ',code,', message = ',msg);
END IF;


DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS rowsToUse;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;

SELECT result;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;

==============================================================
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Probably not related to the error, but you should use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` instead of `REPLACE()`.

Comment: You can also use `rowJson->>'$.userid'` and it will automatically unquote.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @Barmar: I have updated the error message. kindly have a look

Comment: You can't declare a continue handler in the middle of the procedure, it has to be at the top of the procedure, right after the variable declarations.

Comment: @Barmar: Got it. I moved the declaration of handler up above the declaration section and the stored proc got compiled. Thank you.  However, in the error scenario, not even one single row is getting updated in the user_table even if one of the record is not having problem and other has.

Comment: When an error occurs, the entire transaction is rolled back, so nothing is updated. You'll need to insert each row separately, not in bulk.

Comment: @Barmar: Understood, however at least can a message be printed to depict 102-world has problem?